# Meteor Server Side Debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, meteor

I am trying to use node-inspector to debug a Meteor app on windows. I am following this procedure

1. Install node-inspector: `npm install -g node-inspector`
2. Start meteor: `NODE_OPTIONS='--debug' meteor run` (or `mrt run` if you use Meteorite)
3. Start node-inspector
4. Go to the URL given by node-inspector in Chrome

but I am getting this error when I go to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858`

> Error: Is node running with --debug port 5858

Please help

Answer (score 0):

See the section on Windows in the node-inspector [readme](https://npmjs.org/package/node-inspector).

Basically, to enable debug mode for node, you have to get the PID of the node process:

`tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq node.exe"`

And then call this with the PID:

`node -e "process._debugProcess(PID)"`

Comment: I have already tried that but we can only debug main.js by using this method and not out app

Comment: I'd recommend setting up a *nix VM and using that... Windows support for Meteor is still unofficial.